# ¿Cómo seleccionar elementos INTERCALDOS de un array en javascript con .slice y mostrar solo esa porción de elementos

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

`const abecedario = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f', 'g']; // quiero extraer de este array los elementos 'b', 'd', 'f'`

Del array abecedario quiero extraer elementos intercalados, b. d, f.

Comment: Y que codigo usas para eso ??

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por qué indicas en el título que usas slice? probaste algo y no funciona? qué error encuentras? cuál es la salida de ese código y por qué no es correcta? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añáde la info faltante (tu código, los mensajes de error, la salida errada)

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. Quería saber si con el método .slice puedo extraer elementos intercalados de un array y mostrarlos. O si existe otra manera de mostrar solo elementos intercalados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tienes un array de elementos, tendrás que recorrerlo para ir seleccionando los necesarios, hay varias formas:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Luego hay una cosa que se llama "resto" de un número, que sirve para este tipo de operaciones: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

**Solución:**

```
    const abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

    const results = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < abc.length; index++) {

        if (index % 2 === 1) {
            const char = abc[index];
            results.push(char);
        }
    }

    console.log(results);
```

Comment: Podrías empezar en el elemento 1 e incrementar de a 2. Así te evitas la pregunta.